# Unable to add longlistselector tool

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I am working on a windows phone project, under a universal project. A feature I am looking for is the **longlistselector** template, that I am unable to find under toolbox. Am I missing something?

Or rather, if there is a way to arrange a list (*of say countries*), and lets say alphabetically, I wouldn't mind using that either.

VS2013 - U4; W8.1;

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There is no *LongListSelector* in WP8.1 RunTime/Universal app. Take a look at available controls [at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh465351.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

If you need a simple list, take a look [at ListView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listview.aspx).

If you need grouping, then think of using [SemanticZoom](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh781234.aspx). In this case you will find also some help [here at blog](http://www.nogginbox.co.uk/blog/gridview-with-inline-group-headers), [here](http://mikaelkoskinen.net/winrt-step-by-step-tutorial-mvvm-gridview-semanticzoom/) or [here](http://www.visuallylocated.com/post/2014/04/28/Migrating-from-the-LongListSelector-to-the-ListView-in-Windows-Phone-XAML-Apps.aspx).

Comment: Hi Romasz, thanks for that. Does ListView support ~300 items, or might I ask, what is the maximum a ListView can contain? If i have need it to show the list of countries, can I use it?

Comment: @AnonymousPerson It should surely handle 300 items, of course depending on their datatemplate - for example if you have a list of big images, then you can get run out of memery. With large numbers of items think of *Virtualization* and *IncrementalLoading*.

Comment: I see.. thank you for that. i wouldn't be using images, so i wouldn't worry about that. One last thing: if i have like ~100 countries, using listview, will i able to group them by their first letters? like how you have the alphakey groups (is what I think it's called as in xaml)? What I mean to say is can i group them like how we have the contact list grouped, on a Windows Phone. I am hoping this is clear!

Comment: @AnonymousPerson Take a look at SemanticZoom and three links at the end of post above.

Answer (score 1):

**LongListSelector** is not available for Universal apps, it's only available for Silverlight Phone apps. Instead you can use **ListView** .

Example :

```
<phone:LongListSelector ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" >

    <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>

        <DataTemplate>

            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}">

        </DataTemplate>

    </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>

</phone:LongListSelector>
```

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>

    <DataTemplate>

        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" >

    </DataTemplate>

</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

More details check this article : [Migrating from the LongListSelector to the ListView in Windows Phone XAML Apps](http://www.visuallylocated.com/post/2014/04/28/Migrating-from-the-LongListSelector-to-the-ListView-in-Windows-Phone-XAML-Apps.aspx)

Comment: Great! Thanks for that.. But can I use it to present a list of countries? What's the max items it can take?

Comment: The number of items that you can put it in ListView it's constrained by available memory. Yes, you can put 194 items - number of countries in the world - in ListView .